# AngularJS not printing variable

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm currently building my first single page app with angularJS. The variable information stored in my controller is not displaying on the page. After extensively trying to trouble-shoot this I am at a loss to why it isn't displaying.

```
<div ng-repeat="x in pers" class="person">
    <div class="name">{{ pers.person }}</div>
    <div class="out">Out</div>
    <div class="in" >In</div>
    <div class="onsite">On site</div>
    <div class="notes">
        <div class='n'></div>
        <div class='dn'>Delete note</div>
        <div class='an'>Add note</div>
    </div>
```

My controller looks like this.

```
app.controller("MainController", ['$scope',  function($scope) {
    $scope.pers = [
    {
        person: 'Nick',
    },
    {
        person: "Greg",
    }];
}]);
```

The repeat function works as expected and two tables are formed, however both the `div`s with the class name are left without any text in them on the page. I have tried using `ng-binding="pers.person"` as well without any success.

Thanks in advance for any help you can offer with this issue I'm having.

Comment: Replace `pers.person` with `x.person` in your HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should be `{{x.person}}`
you are using `ng-repeat` of `pers` with the alias `x`

Comment: Thanks for that, Makes me feel really simple now I spent so long and didn't figure that out.

Comment: you can accept the answer as verified. and you are welcome